# Trying to combine JSON in R

Tags: r, json

I am new to R and struggling a bit with how to combine JSON.

Background:  I am trying to take values from one API, creating a new JSON payload, and then call another API.  I am stuck trying to create the JSON for the call to the second API.

I iterated through the first API result to mine player data:

[image]

This is a list of player data.  The problem that I am having now is that I need to take this and nest it inside of a parent node:

[image]

So in this example, "50" is the parent node.  I need to take the list from the previous screen cap and put it as a child node to the parent.  In other technologies I would probably convert everything to string.  When I convert to string here, I get a bunch of backslashes in the strings.  I tried a mix of converting to string, converting back and forth to JSON - I don't know if this is the right path (or if there is a more elegant way to do this).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After trying the first recommended answer, I am now getting this.  As you can see, I have an additional node in there.

[image]

Comment: Try [jsonStrings](https://github.com/stla/jsonStrings).

Comment: Thank you so much @StéphaneLaurent!  This gets me closer.  I created a new variable:  {  \"50\": \"hello\"}").  I can see in the example how to replace "hello" with another string.  However, I have two problems.  1)  How do I convert my list to have the escape characters?  2).  How do I use jstring$update with a variable?  I am continuing to search for these answers but thought I would ask here also.

Comment: NVM - I ended up assembling it all as strings and didn't bother with lists.  Thank you for letting me know about this package!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(jsonlite)
# make up some simple heirarchical object and serve it up as json
(somejson <- toJSON(list(a=1,
                        b=list(2,3))))

# Parse it back into r
(somejson_r <- fromJSON(somejson))

# jam it inside of another thing

(my_new_r_thing <- list("50"=list(
  somejson_r
)))

(result <- toJSON(my_new_r_thing))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Nir Graham.  I took your code as-is and I am closer.  I posted a screen shot of the new variable in the original post.  As you can see, I have an extra node in the tree.

Comment: I had an extra set of braces while assembling the children